# Ícone de menu Action Bar sem dropdown

Tags: android, menu, actionbar

Estou tentando remover o menu dropdown do ActionButton Overflow, da Action Bar. 
No caso seria aquele que tem os 3 pontos, um em cima do outro, como padrão e como opção padrão, "Settings". Gostaria de remover esse item "Settings", fazendo com que, ao clicar no ícone do menu, ele já execute uma ação. Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Como está seu arquivo de menu xml? Chegou a usar o atributo `showAsAction="always"`?

Comment: Sim, está como "always".

Answer (score 1):

No menu.xml você cria a opção

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="settings" />
```

E depois vai na sua Activity e

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Implementei algo assim no meu app e funcionou, espero que funcione pra você.

Comment: Muito bom Kamila Brito, seria uma solução para abrir uma nova tela (configurações)